# Can we use one wsimport task for multiple wsdl's in gradle without repeating the similar code?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build, antbuilder

I am writing a gradle task that does wsimport to generate the web service artifacts. The task i wrote is working perfectly fine and is shown below.

```
task wsimport {
    ext.destDir = file('gen')
    doLast {
        ant {
            sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.mkdirs()
            destDir.mkdirs()
            taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
                    classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                    classpath: 'C:/Users/sbhattar/git/java_commons/common/java/lib/jaxws-2.2.6/jaxws-tools.jar'
            )
            wsimport(keep: true,
                    destdir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
                    sourcedestdir: destDir,
                    extension: "true",
                    verbose: "false",
                    quiet: "false",
                    xnocompile: "true",
                 wsdl:"http://spapen2w1.shashwat.com.PlanService_4_0.wsdl") {
                xjcarg(value: "-XautoNameResolution")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But Since I need to generate artifacts from multiple wsdl's i would like to pass something like an array of WSDL paths on the wsdl parameter.  This is the source code that ant.taskdef uses to parse the wsdl. I have already tried passing array of wsdl thinking since `arguments[0]` is an object and since array is an instance of string it might work but it did not. Any help would be appreciated that will help me eliminate code repeatition. Also i am very new to groovy/gradle.

```
public void execute(AntBuilder ant, Object... arguments) {
    def wsdl = arguments[0]
    def extension = arguments[1]
    def destinationDir = arguments[2]
    def classpath = arguments[3]
    def episodes = arguments[4]

    log.info("parsing wsdl '{}' with destination directory of '{}'",
         wsdl, destinationDir)

    ant.taskdef (name : 'wsimport',
         classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
         classpath: classpath)

    def params = [
              wsdl            : wsdl.path,
              verbose         : extension.verbose,
              sourcedestdir   : destinationDir.path,
              keep            : extension.keep,
              wsdlLocation    : extension.wsdlLocation,
              xnocompile      : extension.xnocompile,
              fork            : extension.fork,
              xdebug          : extension.xdebug,
              target          : extension.target,
              xadditionalHeaders : extension.xadditionalHeaders
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to eliminate repetition is to create a list, `wsdlPaths`, and iterate over it. A simple example:

```
task wsimport {
    doLast {
        def wsdlPaths = ["path1", "path2", "path3"]

        wsdlPaths.each { wsdlPath ->
            ant {
                // replace this with your current code as appropriate
                echo(message: "path is ${wsdlPath}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here we merely use `ant.echo` but you should be able to substitute your current code (with slight edits as appropriate).